# How to modify URL with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my URL from

http://website.com/movie.php?id=69

to

http://website.com/movie/69

My htaccess file is completely blank, and I don't know if i need to modify my PHP code.
I've never dealt with htaccess and would prefer having direct assistance instead of some tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+movie\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ movie/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^movie/(\d+)/?$ movie.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: That definitely worked but the original URL still shows in the bottom of the browser when hovering over a movie cover. Shouldn't the new URL be shown?

Comment: Rewrite rule cannot change links in your HTML files. You will need to update those hyperlinks yourself.

Comment: I understand. So in my PHP code i need to change the format to this                 <a href="movie/<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">